# Centering UITableViewCell subviews when row heights vary in a UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am using a slightly larger backgroundView image for the last row of my table. When the last cell is displayed, the imageView, textLabel, and accessoryView are all maintaining the same margin from the bottom of the cell, rather than maintaining their position in the center of the cell like they do on the other rows of smaller height.  This gives the appearance of everything being very low in the larger cell.

I am looking for away to keep these subviews in a standard UITableViewCellStyleDefault centered with the cell despite it's height.

Currently, I'm setting the row height using this delegate:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
        heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.section == 1 && (indexPath.row + 1) == [myList count]) {
        return 65.0;
    }
    else {
        return 50.0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are u adding your own (i.e. custom) subviews to the imageView, textLabel and accessoryView?

Comment: I'm adding my own subview to the accessoryView (just an image view), and can either use the given textLabel for my item title and an image for the imageView, or could use my own subviews.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is probably to subclass `UITableViewCell` and to overwrite the `layoutSubviews` method.